# Print the value of a variable from an IF/ELSEIF/ELSE statement within another variable's value?

Tags: php

I am trying to print the value of a variable from an IF/ELSEIF/ELSE statement within another variable's value. I need to check for the $organize variable; if set to 1, 2, 3 or 4 it will show a special bullet; otherwise, it will show a default bullet. Regardless, I am trying to insert the value of the variable $bullet into the variable $dataset which will be further manipulated down the road (not shown here).

I tried setting the $dataset variable as shown below in the commented version. It didn't work! Any ideas?

```
// $dataset will contain array( 'Category1' => array('Item 1', 'Item2'), ... )

$dataset = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!$row['CategoryID']) {
        $row['CategoryName'] = 'Sort Me';
    }

    if (((isset($organize)) && ($organize=="1"))) { $bullet = "<div class=\"bullet1\">"; } 
    elseif (((isset($organize)) && ($organize=="2"))) { $bullet = "<div class=\"bullet2\">"; } 
    elseif (((isset($organize)) && ($organize=="3"))) { $bullet = "<div class=\"bullet3\">"; } 
    elseif (((isset($organize)) && ($organize=="4"))) { $bullet = "<div class=\"bullet4\">"; } 
    else  { $bullet = "<div class=\"bullet0\">"; }

    // $dataset[$row['CategoryName']][] = 'print $bullet . "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"" . $row['ItemAddress'] . "\">" . $row['ItemTitle'] . "</a>" . $row['ItemNote'] . "</div>"';
    $dataset[$row['CategoryName']][] = "<div class=\"bullet0\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"" . $row['ItemAddress'] . "\">" . $row['ItemTitle'] . "</a>" . $row['ItemNote'] . "</div>";

    $num_articles++;
}
```

Comment: You should really do some light reading here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php - a switch statement will make your life MUCH easier.

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dataset[$row['CategoryName']][] = $bullet . "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"" . $row['ItemAddress'] . "\">" . $row['ItemTitle'] . "</a>" . $row['ItemNote'] . "</div>"';
```

Furthermore, you can clean up you `if/elseif/else` to show this:

```
if (isset($organize)) {
    $org_num = (int) $organize;
    $bullet = "<div class=\"bullet{$org_num}\">";
} else {
    $bullet = "<div class=\"bullet0\">";
}
```

Comment: Or simply `$num = isset($organize) ? (int)$organize : 0; $bullet = "<div class=\"bullet$num\">";`